# feed uncompressed file to command line argument

Tags: python, bash, process-substitution

Let's say I have a gzipped file, but my script only takes in an uncompressed file.

Without modifying the script to take in a compressed file, could I uncompress the file on the fly with bash?

For example:

```
python ../scripts/myscript.py --in (gunzip compressed_file.txt.gz)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a process substitution, as long as the Python script doesn't try to seek backwards in the file:

```
python ../scripts/myscript.py --in <(gunzip compressed_file.txt.gz)
```

Python receives a file name as an argument; the name just doesn't refer to a simple file on disk. It can only be opened in read-only mode, and attempts to use the `seek` method will fail.

---

If you were using `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could use

```
python ../scripts/myscript.py --in =(gunzip compressed_file.txt.gz)
```

and Python would receive the name of an actual (temporary) file that could be used like any other file. Said file would be deleted by the shell after `python` exits, though.